# Determining the first socket connection in socket.io/ property assignment of sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So I'm using socket.io on a node.js server and I'm trying to set up a way to determine which socket client is the first to connect. This client will then be sent a message to tell it to set a game up on the client side. Since I only want this to be emitted to the first client to connect I am attempting to make a check on whether the 'gameCaptain' property on my state object is null. If so, there must have been no connections yet and the server should assign the current socket to the state.gameCaptain property. Then, when other sockets connect, the if statement should no longer pass and they should skip that emission.

```
const state = {
  gameCaptain: null,
  otherThing: null
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  if (state.gameCaptain === null) {
    socket.emit('isGameCaptain', true);
    state.gameCaptain = socket.id;
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't work. While I can assign any other properties of the state object within that if statement, such as:

```
 if (state.gameCaptain === null) {
    socket.emit('isGameCaptain', true);
    state.otherThing = socket.id;
  }
```

if I try to assign anything to the state.gameCaptain property the entire method doesn't run. I must be missing something about the order of evaluation here, but it seems like the if statement is passing the null check, then assigning the gameCaptain property and then going back and failing the null check because of that assignment. I cannot figure it out.

Also, if I'm just going about this the wrong way and you know a better way to assign sockets to variables, please let me know. I just need to determine the first connection and emit to that socket so that the other socket's aren't also asked to set up the game.

Comment: can't duplicate...based on what you posted, it works fine for me.